# Javascript regular expression: save matching value

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following expression in JS (typescript, but I think everyone understands what it transpiles to):

```
  markString(text: string) {
    const regEx = new RegExp(this.partToHighlight, 'ig');
    return text.replace(regEx, `<mark>${this.partToHighlight}<\/mark>`);
  }
```

The problem is that this way, with the 'ig'-option, the matching value can have any case, upper or lower, but is always replaced by the `partToHighlight`-value. Instead the function should read the matched value, save it and output it surrounded with the HTML-tags. How do I do this? I am pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find the one asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace with the found match, `$&`:

```
markString(text: string) {
    const regEx = new RegExp(this.partToHighlight, 'ig');
    return text.replace(regEx, "<mark>$&</mark>");
}
```

Using `$&`, you replace with found match with the the same text found and do not need to hardcode the replacement, nor use any callbacks.

See ["Specifying a string as a parameter"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in comments you will need to use **[RegExp.lastMatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch)** or  [**$&**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), to point out to the matched substring, in your `replace()` method:

```
const regEx = new RegExp(this.partToHighlight, 'ig');
return text.replace(regEx, `<mark>$&<\/mark>`);
```

Comment: Actually, a more appropriate link to the `$&` is the one I provided in my answer, as you also provided the string replacement backreference based solution (it is the same as mine, just there is no need to escape `/` in the replacement pattern, as the single ``\`` in the string literal will be removed by the engine anyway).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well pointed out, thank you, I edited my answer.